# Upload file to Azure webrole application directory

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We've got an Azure cloud service with a web role. I want to upload a plain html file to the web role's application, without doing a full redeploy (the file would be added to the next build anyway). There are multiple instances of the webrole, and the file would need to be on each.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is posible, but not a nice idea for a production environment.
You always can setup remote access to your compute instances and there you can copy paste any file as you want.

Also you can configure any deploy option : FTP, Git Etc...

But... bad idea, really bad idea.

- What if you have 100 instances, Will you made the changes in all of them?
- Who can ensure that every instance runs the same app version?

### And think about:

Because the package is attached to your service and because of that to your instances..

If an error or maintenance task occurs in azure your compute instances will be recreated, when recreated : the last copy of your package is deployed to each compute instance and all other changes you have made in your app or in OS will be lost...

Same could happen in any situation where the instance needs to be recreated by yourself or by azure internal management/operation tasks.